# How to get the name of dir from where a python script is called (not exaclty where it ran)

Tags: python

I have a Python script, named `script.py`. It's located on `~/scripts/script.py`.

I have an alias in `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
alias script='python ~/scripts/script.py'
```

I have some directories in a checked out repository, for example:

```
~/repository/project_dir/module_name/
```

I run on my terminal, inside `~/repository/project_dir/module_name/`, the `script` alias I created. This script has a print statement printing the directory from where the `script.py` was run, but I want it to print from where it was **called**. How do I do it?

(Now, I'm using `os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])` and it prints `~/scripts/script.py` instead of `~/repository/project_dir/module_name/`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
```

For more details, check out the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os-file-dir).

Comment: Thats correct... I've used this command in the past, but I didn't work.. I think I did something wrong at that time. Thanks for the answer, it works as intended! (But it's better to use os.getcwdu to handle unicode).